# Input boxes not lining up

Tags: html, css, text, input, form-submit

I'm new to HTML and last time I've been editing my code I found that my input boxes don't align perfectly. I want them to be just in line on right. Here is the code:

```css
input
{
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  font: normal 15px Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #66004C;
  background: #cdcdcd; 
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;">
 <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;"> 
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" style="background: #66004C; color: #efefef;"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Don't have an account yet? Register!" onclick="window.location='/register.php';" style="border-bottom:  solid 5px #66004C;"/>  
  </form>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Also I searched the web but found no right answer..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this [CSS3 box-sizing Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) in your stylesheet.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding adds extra width to any element. In your case an additional 50px (left + right)

The solution is simple and worth doing in every project:

```
* { Box-sizing: Border-box }
```

```css
input
{
 margin:     auto;
    padding:     25px;
    font:      normal 15px Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    width:      100%;
 border-left:    0;
 border-right:    0;
 border-top:    0;
 border-bottom:    solid 3px #66004C;
    background:    #cdcdcd; 

}
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

```html
<div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;">
 <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;"> 
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" style="background: #66004C; color: #efefef;"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Don't have an account yet? Register!" onclick="window.location='/register.php';" style="border-bottom:  solid 5px #66004C;"/>  
  </form>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `box-sizing` for inputs.

Learn more about [CSS3 box-sizing Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```css
input {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  font: normal 15px Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #66004c;
  background: #cdcdcd; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;">
  <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;"> 
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" style="background: #66004C; color: #efefef;"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Don't have an account yet? Register!" onclick="window.location='/register.php';" style="border-bottom:  solid 5px #66004C;"/>  
 </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main
    {
     align:right;
    }
input {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  font: normal 15px Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #66004c;
  background: #cdcdcd; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align:right;
}



<div id="main" style="float:right; position: relative; ">
  <div style="float: right; position: relative; ">  
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" value="Log In" style="background: #66004C; color: #efefef;"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Don't have an account yet? Register!" onclick="window.location='/register.php';" style="border-bottom:    solid 5px #66004C;"/>  
    </form>     
  </div>
</div>
```